# Azure AD SSO sync users via Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We want to allow a client to use their Azure AD credentials to log into our web application. We currently have an on-premise infrastructure running a .NET Core application so any added benefit of hosting our application on Azure won't help (until we migrate, but I can't see that happening any time soon).

I think that we could get the Azure AD SSO working but I'm not sure how we would be able to sync the Azure AD users to our database programmatically. This is needed because we have a complex set of authorisation rules throughout the application. One possibility would be to create a service application that gathers all users within an Azure AD domain via Graph API and feed them into an API on our end but I'm not sure if I'm missing something that would make this easier. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered Application Proxy? ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy#what-is-application-proxy)

Comment: @Nishant-MSFTIdentity - Thanks for the reply. I may not have been clear but I don't believe Application Proxy would help to **sync users in an Azure AD collection to an on-premise database**. I'm only looking for a way to sync users.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I had recommended App Proxy for authentication without syncing the users. For syncing users from Azure AD to On-prem Database, going via API would be a good approach.